# $().focus not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, setfocus

I am trying to make an autocomplete functionality and want to apply focus to the first item in a list of matches once the user pressed the 'down' arrow.

This fires on keyup within the search box and manages the type of keypress fine:

```
   var handleKeyCode = function (e) {

    switch (e.which) {

        // Arrow up
        case 38:
            alert("Up");
            break;

        // Arrow down
        case 40:
            console.log("This fires fine...");
            arrowDown();
            break;

        // Other keys
        default:
            filter();
    };

    e.preventDefault();

};
```

This fires once the down arrow has been pressed, however, DOESNT apply the focus code for some reason. When I console log the selector it is returning the correct list item, just failing to focus.

```
var arrowDown = function () {

    console.log("Code below finds the selector fine:");
    console.log($('.scheme-list li:visible:first'));

    $('.scheme-list li:visible:first').focus(function () {
        console.log("The selector is not focused AND...");
        console.log("Anything in here is not fired!");
    });
};
```

Comment: `.focus(function...)` binds an event handler. To fire the event, send it without the argument `.focus()`

Comment: Only forms controls can take focus anyway, and `<div>` elements are not form controls.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - aah okay, that makes sense! I am trying to focus onto a list item, so I assume the same cannot be done. I guess I will have to apply classes to replicate a focused state or something

Comment: @blgt .focus() doesn't work either. I am assuming because of the reason suggested above

Comment: Please show enough HTML to create a repro. Are the items in the list actually focusable elements?

Answer (score 0):

`$elem.focus(function () { /* do something */ })` will do something whenever the element gets focus.

`$elem.focus()` or `$elem.trigger('focus')` will set the focus on the element.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was trying to focus on a non-focusable element I.e NOT a form control.

To get around this I added a `tabindex` HTML attribute to each of my list items to enable the focus event on these elements like so:

```
<li tabindex="0"> Some item I want to focus </li>
```

This then allowed me to call `$().focus()`and worked fine.